# Deleting data from dictionary based on starting letter

Tags: python, list, dictionary, pycharm

I have a data set with 4 columns, I have already opened, read, and made each column into a key/dictionary, I am trying to filter out any data which begins with a certain letter, e.g. for key DA, any value in this key with a certain starting letter (e.g. E) will result in the row being deleted. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Hi James. What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) function to check if a string starts with a certain letter. So in your case, it can be something like the following:

```
list_dictionary = [
    {'KeyYa': 'abc', 'KeyDa': 'def', 'KeyBa': 'ghi', 'KeySa': 'jkl'},
    {'KeyYa': 'abc', 'KeyDa': 'Edef', 'KeyBa': 'ghi', 'KeySa': 'jkl'},
    {'KeyYa': 'abc', 'KeyDa': 'Gdef', 'KeyBa': 'ghi', 'KeySa': 'jkl'},
    {'KeyYa': 'abc', 'KeyDa': 'Edef', 'KeyBa': 'ghi', 'KeySa': 'jkl'}
]

filtered = []
for line_dict in list_dictionary:
    if not line_dict['KeyDa'].startswith('E'):
        filtered.append(line_dict)

print(filtered)
```

This prints:

```
[{'KeyDa': 'def', 'KeyYa': 'abc', 'KeyBa': 'ghi', 'KeySa': 'jkl'}, {'KeyDa': 'Gdef', 'KeyYa': 'abc', 'KeyBa': 'ghi', 'KeySa': 'jkl'}]
```

If you're comfortable with the `filter` function and `lambda`, you can also do this concisely like this:

```
filtered = list(filter(lambda line: not line['KeyDa'].startswith('E'), list_dictionary))
```